# Sublime mysteriously stops indexing

Tags: sublimetext3

I noticed that Sublime started giving me incomplete results when hovering over a method to go to its source.  I figured the indexes had gotten corrupted, so I made a backup folder and moved the indexes there, thinking that Sublime would automatically rebuild the indexes.

Nothing.  Clicking on Help > Indexing status revealed no workers, no attempt to re-index.

I finally remembered that the last time this happened, a preference had gotten changed.  Sure enough, when I opened my preferences, I found this at the bottom of the file:

```
    // "index_files": false,  // HOW DID THIS NONSENSE GET HERE?  NEVER, NEVER, NEVER!
    "index_files": false,
```

The first line is from the first time this happened, and I commented it out.  The second line has just appeared out of thin air-- I didn't put it there!

My question is, does anybody know why this would happen, and is there any way to prevent it?

(Sublime Build 4169 on Windows 10)

Comment: Same here, running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. it'd be useful to know what OS are you running Sublime Text with

Comment: @alfx added build and OS to the question.  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: oh well, same build but different OS. sounds like a bug in 4169 to me